# falha url rewrite slim iis 10

Tags: php, iis, slim, web.config

Estou tentando seguir o tutorial do slim [aqui](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html), porém sempre dá page not found quando acesso localhost:8080/hello/alan.

Estou usando o iis 10. Instalei o url rewrite 2.0, e meu web.config é assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="slim" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

A estrutura de diretórios da minha aplicação é:

.

├── project

│   └── src

│       └── public

A raiz do site é a pasta public e nela estão o arquivo index.php e web.config.

O código do index.php é:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('hello/{name}', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Procurei ajuda na internet e não consegui nenhuma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O único problema é que você esqueceu de colocar a barra antes do seu método hello. Você colocou :`$app->get('hello/{name}'` ao invés de `$app->get('/hello/{name}'`

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

**Obs.:** Não precisa colocar `function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) pode usar direto`function($request, $response, $args)`

Um jeito mas otimizado deste código seria:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;


$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->write('Hello: ' . $args['name']
    );
});

$app->run();
```